# Reduce downtime when swapping out job manager and task managers

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

### Context

I'm running a standalone Flink deployment (Flink v1.12.7) without High Availability in Application mode and non-reactive mode. I have  1 JobManager and 2 TaskManagers. They are running on ECS in which one ECS service is the JobManager with a task count of 1 and another ECS service is the TaskManager with a task count of 2. The deployment strategy I'm using for both services is a rolling update with a min of 100% and max of 200%. This means that when I deploy a new image to the JobManager, ECS first spins up a new JobManager and then spins the old one down.

### Problem

When ECS spins the old JobManager down thus cutting over to the new JobManager, the TaskManagers go down (i.e. don't process any input) for about a minute with very intermittent logging of errors. After about a minute, they register successfully with the new JobManager and continue streaming as usual. The same happens if I were to deploy a new image to the TaskManagers while keeping the same JobManager intact. I'd like to reduce this downtime and make the TaskManagers and JobManager more responsive to the other being swapped out.

### What I've tried

I've tried reducing the `heartbeat.timeout` from 50s (the default) to 20s hoping that that would shave off some time off the 1 min of downtime but no luck. I've also increased the memory and CPU just in case but that didn't help either.

Any help or ideas on which configuration parameters to tune would be helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Did you tried to have a HA setup with more than one job-manager. No clue if this works with ECS but the zookeeper setup should be straight forward: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/ha/overview/

Comment: [Zero-downtime upgrades of Flink applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hyt3YrtKQAM) may give you some good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same problem.  And I read a lot about the HA setup / Zero downtime application upgrade.  None of that work at my case

HA setup looks cool, but it only resolve the problem of jobmanager crash, but how about a new jobamanger with a updated application code started up and swapping the old job managers? "Standalone mode"

Zero-downtime video solution is to keep two jobs running for a while.  It will have many side effects, for example duplicate data send to sink, and it can be very dangerious in many use cases.

Flink just doens't have a feature like "Start from latest checkpoint", I know I can use --fromsavepoint flag and it works for the checkpoint, but I don't want to manually go to the directory and figure out which one is the latest checkpoint....